# Using regex to get specific string in it's entirity php

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing email **raw text** bodies, and they have no HTML, so it's a multi line string essentially.

I thought I created a regex to catch: `Quote: #403` I need that back as [Quote, 403] from the entirety of this large string.

So heres an example:

```
$body = "
Test Person
Tester
(123) 123-1234
 <mailto:xxxxxx@xxxxx.com> xxxxxx@xxxxx.com
xxxxxx@xxxxx.com




Your Information:

Name: Last, First
Email: xxxxxx@xxxxx.com <mailto:xxxxxx@xxxxx.co> 
Phone: (123) 123-1234

Quote: #403";

preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+: #[0-9]+$/i', $body,$matches);

var_dump($matches); // => array(0) {}
```

Matches is empty. Based on my understanding this should have worked.

**Thoughts?**

Comment: Instead of `/i` try `/m`

Comment: Add the `m` flag for multiline: [See demo](https://tio.run/##dVDBasJAEL3PVwwaMGJSU/ViqrY9tFQQieBFQyprsjaBbibsbkr159N1T2LowDyGx5v3hqnyqmlmz9FHBOAcKTvjHDuw5UpjxKWi0s5cgvs4GvfRgG96AjgTrPjWFP7aerH4kJJY4D0DLeJaO6olLssTScF0QWUIsGaCh7hiSnv4Xkil4e0aErYc/wtfIEQ5lcbk7lrY1KQN3Z0E484TQCX518HkprnbG37GzL@8@vtkYARx4E@TgTMsRM9D@xDPsUKu@mbxh8lDVovKvSWb5g8)

Comment: `^` asserts the beginning of the string, not the beginning of the line, unless you're using `/m` (multiline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the "start" and "end" characters and make it multi-line:

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+: #[0-9]+/m', $body,$matches);
```

Comment: This works and I technically can "explode" on the hash to get the quote number. I was just hoping to use regex to get it back in the array I wanted: `[Quote, 403]` but this works.

Comment: @TheWebs You can use *capturing groups* [(demo)](https://tio.run/##dVDRSsNAEHzfr1hqoHeY2Nb2xbRWfVAURCL0xZY2nOnVHPSy4e4i1uK3x/PAl5Yu7DAMw8yydVm37eQme8wAonda7/AaOzCT1mEmjaUqcGmADS6HHD0kfkeAEy3U1lH6FeY24EVBeoqHChwJ8EaNwadqQ0YLp6hKAV6Elik@C@tifFDGOrj/a0iP4k41TxGykiofcnAqvDbkvHw26g87YwC1YbWRH7mvLkrW7a3YQiTfd8l8ec69iy36yZWnUU93Yww/iaPglZZz3APipzD5utE1E8aIXW63qpDs3xMPOB/DD7TtLw)

Comment: @bobblebubble What would I do with out you :D Hahahaha thanks friend :D

Comment: : ) You welcome @TheWebs